# Is $(t,|t|)$ a smooth submanifold of $\mathbb{R^2}$?

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I can't figure it if the subset of of $S=\{(t,|t|)|\in \mathbb{R}\}$ is a submanifold of $\mathbb{R^2}$. I am pretty sure we can give it a smooth manifold stucture but I don't understand if this guarantees that it is a submanifold of $\mathbb{R^2}$

Answer (score 0):

No, it is the union of two half lines $D_1=\{(t,t), t>0\}$ and $\{(t,-t),t<0\}$ if it was a (1-dimensional) submanifold, it would have been possible to define the tangent space of $(0,0)$, but $(1,1)$ is tangent to $D_1$  at $(0,0)$ and $(-1,1)$ is tangent to $D_2$ at $(0,0)$ so the tangent space is not defined at $(0,0)$.

Comment: This is a correct assertion but your "because" just asserts the definition. I think you need to say a little more to turn it into a proof. A picture will help.

Comment: This answer makes no sense. $S$, by definition has a well defined tangent space at the point $(0,0)$. If it is not a smooth manifold there is nothing to ask. When it is a smooth manifold it does have its tangent at $(0,0)$. What you need to prove is that the map from this tangent space to the tangent space of $\mathbb{R}^2$ at $(0,0)$ cannot be injective.

Comment: @orole certainly your comment make a lot of sense, but i don't get it, do you know the definition of the tangent space of a submanifold ?

Comment: You need to take the smooth manifold $S$ and assume $f:S\to\mathbb{R}^2$ is a smooth embedding. Then go to charts around $(0,0)\in S$ and around $(0,0)\in\mathbb{R}^2$. Compose the three functions to get one function from $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^2$. Then, by the same left-right argument, show that its derivative at $0$ is the vector $0$. Therefore $Tf$ can't be injective. Yes, I know the definition. Do you? $S$ can perfectly be a smooth manifold on its own.

Comment: I think Tsemo's answer gave me a good direction to go to. I would say that IF $S$ was a submanifold of $\mathbb{R^2}$ then the half lines $l_1=\{(t,t)|t\geq 0\}$ and $l_2=\{(t,-t)|t\leq 0\}$ would be submanifolds of $S$. Because the the inclusion of $l_1,l_2$ in $S$ would give an inclusion into the tangets spaces , we would have that the tangent space of $S$ at $0$) would be $2$ dimensional which is abusrd.

Comment: @orole please review the definition of the tangent space of a submanifold.

Comment: @TsemoAristide You are the one that needs to [review the definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submanifold).

Comment: @NickA. this is exactly what I am thinking about.

Comment: It is non-sensical to start with a smooth manifold and end up proving that it doesn't have a tangent space. It does, by definition.

Comment: @orole This is what bugged me and I see the subtetly now. It is one thing  to say that a set can be an one-dimensional smooth manifold and another thing to say that this set as a subset of a manifold can be a submanifold. I think that this example illustrates just that.

Comment: @orole I hope you understand this explanation of Nick now.

Comment: @TsemoAristide You are the one that needs to understand it. It shows why your argument makes no sense. Anyway, what I am saying is beyond trivial. If you still don't see why your argument makes no sense there is no much more that I can do.

Comment: @NickA. By the way. In the comment above that you conclude that the tangent space of $S$ would be $2$-dimensional. That is not really the right conclusion. The supposed embedding might shrink the vectors from each side to zero, and that is ok, but not for an embedding. For example, in $f(t)=(g(t),|g(t)|)$ with $g(t)=e^{-t^{-2}}$ for $t>0$, $=-e^{-t^{-2}}$ for $t<0$ and $=0$ for $t=0$, that is what happens.

Comment: @orole From my understanding , since the inclusion is 1-1 so must be it's pushforward. I will search my books and give a direct reference when I can.

Comment: @NickA. That's the definition, yes. That is what a proper proof should end up, in contradicting that. I already put a link above.